# opencv_annotation error message; 'opencv_annotation' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, opencv

I want to use OpenCV's integrated annotation tool as per https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/dc/d88/tutorial_traincascade.html.

The tutorial says this command will open up a window containing the images for you to annotate using your cursor.

```
opencv_annotation --annotations=/path/to/annotations/file.txt --images=/path/to/image/folder/
```

But when I try to use it:

```
# Attempt 1
opencv_annotation --annotations=C:\Users\my_user\po_images\pos_anno.txt --images=C:\Users\my_user\po_images

# Attempt 2
opencv_annotation --annotations=\Users\my_user\po_images\pos_anno.txt --images=\Users\my_user\po_images

# Attempt 3   
opencv_annotation --annotations \Users\my_user\po_images\pos_anno.txt --images \Users\my_user\po_images\
```

I get an error message:

```
'opencv_annotation' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I've definitely got openCV installed:

```
C:\Users\my_user>pip show opencv-python
Name: opencv-python
Version: 4.5.1.48
```

So where am I going wrong?

I'm on Python 3.9.1, Windows 10.

Thanks!

Comment: pip installs only the python cv2 module, NOT apps like `opencv_annotation.exe`

Answer (score 2):

( Please Note That The Following Solution is based on Windows OS , Other Platforms may Not be Compatible with the Following Solution )

I think the `opencv_annotation` is excluded in opencv 4.5.1 ?

I'm also using opencv 4.5.3 and the `opencv_annotation` is not a command-line tool ( I think )

Maybe you can follow this youtube video ( [Training a Cascade Classifier - OpenCV Object Detection in Games #8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XrCAvs9AePM&t=605s) ) or the same [text-based tutorial](https://learncodebygaming.com/blog/training-a-cascade-classifier) to create positive and negative samples. I'll also describe how I make these samples below ( the “*Handling Positive Samples*” section may solve your issue ( maybe ) ) :

## My Dir. Structure

```
main.py

img_source

    Source1
        Positive
            img1.png
            img2.png
            ...

        Negative
            img1.png
            img2.png
            ...

    Source2
        Positive
            img1.png
            img2.png
            ...

        Negative
            img1.png
            img2.png
            ...

    ...
```

// Please Note that All the Python Code Below is Run Inside the `main.py`

## Collecting Samples

I just searched online and screenshot it manually by myself. Note that you may don't need to crop it

for negative samples : I just randomly take some unrelated pictures or search online and dump them into the `Negative` dir.

for positive samples : I just manually take screenshots of it + collect from online

## Handling Negative Samples

create a file called `bg.txt` and run the following code to add each image path to the `bg.txt` in each `Negative` folder

```
import os

img_source_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), <image source>)
_ = os.listdir(img_source_dir)

for sources in _:
    os.chdir(os.path.join(img_source_dir, sources))
        
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(img_source_dir, sources, "Negative")):
        os.mkdir("Negative")
        
    os.chdir("./Negative")
        
    f = open("bg.txt", "w")
    content = ""
        
    for file in os.listdir("."):
            
        if j != "bg.txt":
            content += os.path.join(img_source_dir, sources, "Negative", file) + "\n"
        
    f.write(content)
    f.close()
```

## Handling Positive Samples ( the major answer for your question )

Since the `opencv_annotation` etc. cannot be found , I downloaded the `opencv-3.4.11-vc14_vc15.exe` from [SOURCEFORGE](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/3.4.11/)

Run the downloaded file ( should be .exe )

In the extracted file `opencv` , go to : `./build/x64/vc15/bin/`
and you will find `opencv_annotation.exe` `opencv_createsamples.exe` `opencv_traincascade.exe` etc. there

then go to the `\Positive` dir. and type what you did before

in my case :

```
C:\Users\PAUL\Downloads\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin\opencv_annotation.exe --annotations=positive.txt --images=./
```

follow the instruction to crop the positive image , remember to press key "c" to accept the selection

when done , it will create a file called `positive.txt` in the `./Positive` dir. containing [ img_path number_of_sample_for_each_img coordinates ]

then we will need to create a vector file from these positive annotations , by :

in my case :

```
C:\Users\PAUL\Downloads\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin\opencv_createsamples.exe -info positive.txt -w 24 -h 24 -num 1000 -vec positive.vec
```

it will create a `positive.vec` file from the given information in `Positive.txt` ( in the same dir. ) containing [<= 1000] vectors ( from `-num` )

- for lazy guy like me :

the following code will create a `\Positive` dir. inside the `<image source>\<sources>` dir. and will annotate + create [<= 1000] vectors for each set of sources ( like what we did above )

in my case :

```
import os

img_source_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), <image source>)
_ = os.listdir(img_source_dir)
    
for sources in _:
    
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(img_source_dir, sources, "Positive")):
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(img_source_dir, sources, "Positive"))
            
    os.chdir(os.path.join(img_source_dir, sources, "Positive"))
    # annotate
    os.system("C:/Users/PAUL/Downloads/opencv/build/x64/vc15/bin/opencv_annotation.exe --annotations=positive.txt --images=./")
    # create samples
    os.system("C:/Users/PAUL/Downloads/opencv/build/x64/vc15/bin/opencv_createsamples.exe -info positive.txt -w 24 -h 24 -num 1000 -vec positive.vec")
```

## The Updated Dir. Structure

also create a `\cascade` folder in each source for our trained cascades

```
main.py

img_source

    Source1
        Positive
            img1.png
            img2.png
            ...
            positive.txt
            positive.vec

        Negative
            img1.png
            img2.png
            ...
            bg.txt

        cascade
            
    Source2
        Positive
            img1.png
            img2.png
            ...
            positive.txt
            positive.vec

        Negative
            img1.png
            img2.png
            ...
            bg.txt

        cascade
            
    ...
```

- for lazy guy like me :

```
# create the cascade folder for each source

import os

img_source_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), <image source>)
_ = os.listdir(img_source_dir)

for sources in _:
    os.chdir(os.path.join(img_source_dir, sources))

    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(img_source_dir, sources, "cascade")):
        os.mkdir("cascade")
```

## Train Cascade Classifier Model

Go to the `Source` dir. which contain the `Positive` `Negative`
and `cascade` folder

For each `Source` dir. :
Use the following command to train the cascade :

in my case :

```
C:/Users/PAUL/Downloads/opencv/build/x64/vc15/bin/opencv_traincascade.exe -data ./cascade/ -vec ./Positive/positive.vec -bg ./Negative/bg.txt -w 24 -h 24 -numPos 200 -numNeg 100 -numStages 20
```

It will create `.xml` files in the `\cascade` dir. using the information given e.g. `positive.vec` in `\Positive\` folder , `bg.txt` in `\Negative\` folder , etc.

If you get errors like

```
OpenCV: terminate handler is called! The last OpenCV error is:
...
Can not get new positive sample
```

You may either lower the `-numPos` or the `-minHitRate`

## Implementation

Below we will use `opencv` and `PIL` ( Pillow ) to detect obj. in one single image by using the cascade generated above

```
import cv2
from PIL import ImageGrab, Image  # ImageGrab for screenshot ; Image for loading img.
import numpy as np
import os

# screenshot
# _screenshot = ImageGrab.grab()
# _frame = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(_screenshot), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# test img.
img = Image.open(os.path.join(<path to where the img locate>))
_frame = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# load the trained models
cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(<path to where the cascade.xml locate>)

# object detection
rect = cascade.detectMultiScale(_frame)
"""
rectangle(s) detected of structure :
[ [x, y, w, h]
  [x, y, w, h]
  ...]

where x and y is the x- y- coordinate in the img ; 
w and h is the width and height relative to the x, y coordinate
"""

for x, y, width, height in rect:
    # draw rectangle on the _frame
    # color --> (r, g, b)
    cv2.rectangle(_frame, pt1 = (x, y), pt2 = (x + height, y + width), color = (255, 0, 0), thickness = 2)

# visualize it
# display the images
cv2.imshow("title", _frame)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

## Reference

- OpenCV Doc. : [Cascade Classifier Training](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/d88/tutorial_traincascade.html)
- Text-based Tutorial by Ben : [Training a Cascade Classifier](https://learncodebygaming.com/blog/training-a-cascade-classifier)
- SOURCEFORGE : [Where I download the `opencv-3.4.11-vc14_vc15.exe`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/3.4.11/)

## Code Snippet

- Get Number of Positive and Negative Samples from Each Source

Just in case you need it

```
import os

img_source_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), <image source>)
_ = os.listdir(img_source_dir)

for sources in _:
    print(sources)
    
    # positive
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(img_source_dir, sources, "Positive", "positive.txt")):
        f = open(os.path.join(img_source_dir, sources, "Positive", "positive.txt"), "r")
        content = f.read()
        f.close()
        
        content = content.strip().split("\n")
        n = 0
        
        for line in content:
            tmp = line.split(" ")
            
            if int(tmp[1]) > 0:
                n += int(tmp[1])
                
        print(f"Positive Samples : {n}")
    
    # negative
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(img_source_dir, sources, "Negative", "bg.txt")):
        f = open(os.path.join(img_source_dir, sources, "Negative", "bg.txt"), "r")
        content = f.readlines()
        print(f"Negative Samples : {len(content)}")
        f.close()
    
    print()
```

---

Please correct it if anything is incorrect

Any suggestions are welcome  : )